# Count and sum of numbers in python

Tags: python, count, sum, range

Very new to coding/python and needed a little assistance. Essentially, this code asks for a starting and ending number which displays all the numbers in that range which are divisible by 3. So, if 0 5 were input, only 3 would display. I need help displaying the count and sum of the displayed numbers. Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

```
start = int(input( 'Please enter a starting number: '))
end = int(input( 'Please enter an ending number: '))

rng = range(start, end ,3)
for i in rng:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 2):

To get the range to be inclusive of the end number you need to do `range(start, end + 1)`. Then we can use a list comprehension to filter the range to include only those numbers divisible by 3.

We now have a list which we can print and also call `sum` on to get the total sum.

To avoid including 0 in the list we can also test that the value is not falsey i.e. 0 before including it. Remove the `n and` part if you do want to include 0.

```
start = int(input( 'Please enter a starting number: '))
end = int(input( 'Please enter an ending number: '))

vals = [n for n in range(start, end + 1) if n and n % 3 == 0]

print('The values are %r and the sum is %d' % (vals, sum(vals)))
```

Output

```
Please enter a starting number: 0
Please enter an ending number: 5
The values are [3] and the sum is 3
```